# JDeveloper Out of memory error

Tags: java, configuration, config, jdeveloper

I am using JDeveloper for my application. It was working fine until yesterday. I updated my CVS and when i try to build i get the below error:

```
The system is out of resources.
    [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
    [javac] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I changed the conf file to `AddVMOption     -Xmx512M` but still see the same issue. CHnaged it from 128-512 and see getting the same issue. What else I need to change?

Comment: Are you trying to do any deployments?

Comment: then please tell us when you get this error. When you load the project? In which file did you add the option? ide.conf or jdev.conf?

Comment: I get this error when I build the project. Added this option in jdev.conf